# jQuery UI Dialog Resizing breaks content width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange bug here, and I have a few ideas what might be causing this. First let me tell you the issue.

Whenever I resize my dialog box, the "ui-dialog-content" width is changed to be less than the width of the rest of the dialog. It's difficult to explain, so I created a short video showing the issue and how removing the "width" property added by jQuery when resizing, it fixes the issue.

Video: http://www.screencast.com/t/3oczroeEZUg

I've found that it's an issue with Bootstrap 3 and jQuery UI together. I removed the Bootstrap 3 stylesheet (which broke my entire website design) and it fixed the issue. It means there is CSS somewhere that is conflicting between the two.

I'm not sure what code to add to this that will help you come up with a solution. I just use jQuery UI and Bootstrap 3. I suppose I can just hope others have had this issue before and can help me find a solution, I tried searching but didn't come up with anything, I might have just not been searching the right keywords.

Edit: I've tracked the issue to these lines in bootstrap.css

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Looking in how to override this on JUST the dialog right now, because removing this code will break my entire site.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it's not 100% perfect but it does the job well enough.

As the edit in my post says, the issue was being caused by this CSS in Bootstrap 3.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I created a file, and included it after I included bootstrap which overrides these settings for the dialog only.

```
.ui-dialog-content {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

This causes the dialog to behave, mostly. A few issues still persist, although they are minor issues.

1. The middle section is still about 5 pixels too wide now. As shown here: http://www.screencast.com/t/0nzFa9Kd
2. Everytime you click and resize the box, the button area is cut off by about 5 - 10 pixels each. Eventually the buttons are nearly hidden completely, as shown here: http://www.screencast.com/t/EbNT7JjGX

These issues are minor in comparison, so for now I'll ignore them. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to override above styles , you can add styles to the div by adding a class to it where dialog box is binded. Please note that you should use custom classes instead of overriding internal class tags.

```
.divClass{
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    -moz-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing: initial;
}

.divClass:before,
.divClass:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
    -moz-box-sizing: initial;
    box-sizing: initial;
}
```

din't tested it with jquery ui and bootstrap , but guess it should work.
box-sizing property initial should work for more properties check this : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: The Dialog box code is all generated by jQuery, I don't write the HTML. I MIGHT be able to give another class to it using one of their functions, however is this really needed? What are the disadvantages to just overriding the code of the Library I use? (In this case, Bootstrap.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong , the only problem is if you play with jquery ui classes than if someone else make use of jquery dialog will get your styles and in case you upgrade in future , there could be problem. It can be handled without affecting lib is by adding a class or id to the div with which dialog box would be instantiated i.e $( "#dialog" ).dialog();, css will be #dialog .ui-dialog-content { // styles }

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-dialog,ui-dialog-conent {
       -webkit-box-sizing: content-box!important;
       -moz-box-sizing:content-box!important;
       box-sizing: content-box!important;
}
```

this is just work for me!